# Does iphone data migration also transfer the data of deleted photos/videos?

Tags: iphone, recovery

So this question might be somewhat confusing, but I will try to be as clear as I can.

If I perform data migration from iphone A to iphone B, does iphone B also receive data of deleted photos, videos, etc?

If I performed data recovery on iphone B, would photos that were deleted more than 30 days ago in iphone A be possibly recovered?

Comment: Please see [ask], this isn't a general tech helpdesk.