# Can I restore deleted photos/videos from an iphone backup?

Tags: iphone, backup, recovery

So, I have an iphone backup file of Iphone SE (1st gen).
The backup was not encrypted.

If I restore this backup file to any iphone, will I be able to perform data recovery and recover
deleted photos and videos(deleted more than 30 days ago)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152363/does-iphone-data-migration-also-transfer-the-data-of-deleted-photos-videos#comment136011626_77152363